# How to use QLPreviewPanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, quicklook

How do I use `QLPreviewPanel`? I know it wasn't a public API before, but it is in 10.6. How can I use it to show a preview of a file in a standard QuickLook panel?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [QuickLookDownloader](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/) code. It walks you through a couple of things you need to do to incorporate `QLPreviewPanel` into your code. Some of these include:

1. Making your objects conform to the `QLPreviewItem` protocol - this tells Quick Look where to find the file you want to preview (and you are previewing files - you can't pass in custom data).
2. Defining a data source and delegate for the `QLPreviewPanel` (if you're worked with `NSTableView`s before, this should be pretty familiar).
3. Configuring the preview panel via the `QLPreviewPanelController` protocol (where you assign the data source and delegate).
4. Displaying shared preview panel.

Items 1-3 are handled in the `MyDocument` class of the sample code. Toggling the display is mostly handled in the `AppDelegate` class. There's also support in the `DownloadsTableView` class that toggles the `QLPreviewPanel` via the space key, a la the Finder.

Comment: Hi Jablair, Can I ask what you mean by (and you are previewing files - you can't pass in custom data).?

Comment: QLPreviewPanel reads data from files - the `previewItemURL` method requires you to pass back a file URL. I was trying to say you couldn't give QLPreviewPanel an HTML string or a chunk of PDF data and expect it to render a preview. If that's what you've got, you'd need to write the data to a temp file and preview. Keep in mind, I'm talking about displaying the preview panel in your own app, not writing a QuickLook importer for a custom data type.

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining that. I'm wondering if I should delete my Answer,Now it does not seem to really answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly Apples [QuickLookDownloader](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/QuickLookDownloader/Introduction/Intro.html) Demo uses Obj-C. I extended
[Josh's Demo](https://github.com/josh-/QLPreviewView-NSPopover-example) with a show panel functionality to show how it is done in Swift:
[Panel and Popover example](https://github.com/Deitsch/QLPreviewView-example)

Answer (score 0):

I am just looking at this myself. And have found that Apple provide a good guide with examples in the [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html), Also there is a good example code and files here -> [animgifqlgen](http://sourceforge.net/projects/animgifqlgen/)

I am using the Enriched HTML method, which seems to be working for what I need.

The idea is to Use what ever code you would normally use to parse the info on the file. And use html for the layout and embedding the parsed info,the html is then displayed within the QL Panel. A lot of the normal html code works like size width length,bgcolor,src ...

The example will show how to write the code including the html parts.Which uses a NSMutableString and its appendString and appendFormat: to build the html.

I have not tried the other methods yet.

For testing I just configured the Document Content Type UTIs in the plist and the put a copy of the built product (the plugin) in my /Users/username/Library/QuickLook/ folder.

You may have to create the Folder.

Note that when you want to replace the plugin in the QuickLook folder by drag and dropping a new copy in the folder, it may be in use.
Just put the old one in the trash. I also found it helped quitting the Quick Look Helper process using the Activity Monitor app. Doing so made sure I was seeing the results from the New version plugin rather than the old one still in memory. ( I sure someone will tell me I am doing bad ;-)  )

Comment: Bummer, the animgifqlgen link is dead. Any idea where the project went?

Comment: Oops, I think the link I originally posted missed so characters of the end. Fixed.