# How to get url preview like in Apple's Mail?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, preview, nsdatadetector

If you move your mouse over a link in Mail.app, you get such triangle and by clicking it you get instant preview of the link. Please give me a hint how to do this?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you know where the links are in the text, I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312441/1362154 "answer") and the QuickLookDownloader code will be informative.

Answer (score 0):

The square button with triangle that you see is an instance of NSDataDetector finding something useful. Search the docs and the sample code and WWDC session videos for NSDataDetector